# How to specify yaw in org.bukkit.Location?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Imagine I want to put some entity into a world at different angles. To do this, I need to specify yaw in `org.bukkit.Location`.

What value should I pass as yaw for

1. 0 or 360 degrees (no rotation, see *scene05_yaw1* below),
2. 90 degrees rotation (*scene05_yaw2*),
3. 180 degrees rotation (*scene05_yaw3*) and
4. 270 degrees rotation (*scene05_yaw4*)

?

In the [Bukkit Javadoc](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Location.html#Location(org.bukkit.World,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float,%20float)) I read that yaw is measured in degrees (i. e. I can pass the values 0, 90, 180 and 270 in the above cases, respectively). In the [description of Minecraft protocol](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Classic_server_protocol) I read that yaw must be recalculated and that Minecraft uses a [non-traditional system](https://github.com/chraft/c-raft/wiki/Vectors,-Location,-Yaw-and-Pitch-in-C%23raft) for angle measurement.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to specify a pitch/yaw, you simply use the necessary constructor: `Location(world world, double x, double y, double z, float yaw, float pitch)`

If you just want to know what to know what value pass in, just test it and see. The yaw and pitch are defined in the Bukkit docs as:

`"yaw - The absolute rotation on the x-plane, in degrees"`

`"pitch- The absolute rotation on the y-plane, in degrees"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the only differences regarding the yaw of an entity in minecraft is that instead of the angle 0º or 360º pointing towards the point (1, 0) like in a usual unit circle, an angle of 270º in minecraft points towards (1, 0), the former value being the X coordinate and the latter the Z coordinate.

You can also use negative values for the yaw as well as values greater than 360 or less than -360. Minecraft's implementation can also be a bit confusing when it comes to cardinal directions (for example: 90º points towards negative X or West).

However if you only want to change an entities direction you can do this simply using values between 0 and 360 and making an entity look towards a cardinal direction can be done like you already mentioned in your question by setting the yaw to 0º, 90º, 180º or 270º.

So if you want to make an entity spawn in with "180 degrees rotation" you need to ask yourself what origin you want to rotate *from*, whether you're okay with rotating the entity 180 degrees from where minecraft places 0º degrees or whether you want to rotate 180 degrees from the normal unit circle 0º, which would face in the -X direction and would have to be translated to 90º in Minecraft.

On a regular unit circle, 180 degrees rotation would point towards (-1, 0). Setting an entity's yaw to a value of 180 in minecraft is completely valid, but the unit vector of the direction the entity is facing will point towards (0, -1), negative Z or North. Rotating that entity by another 90 degrees will make it face East. If this doesn't matter, setting the values as you described in your question should work just fine.